# nginx ingress controller routing doesn't work as expected

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, routes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster with an application (deployment + ClusterIp service), nginx ingress controller, cert manager and letsencrypt issuer.

Here the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
```

This is the the ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - <myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: <myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

It works correctly, responding to the url `https://<myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com`.

Now I need to change the path like in :

```
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - <myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: <myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sub
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

I would expect to browse my app at `https://<myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com/sub`.

Instead I get

`This <myapp>.<myregion>.cloudapp.azure.com page can’t be found`

What I am doing wrong?

I tried to find examples online, but couldn't find any that helped me understand what's wrong.

**EDIT**

What happens behind the scenes (dev tools) is:

1. The browser sends a request to /sub
2. The ingress routes to the correct service, rewriting the url to /
3. The application receives the request correctly
4. The application wants to redirect the browser to a login url (e.g. /login)
5. The browser receives a redirect (302) to /login and executes it
6. The ingress doesn't see the /sub in the redirect url, so it doesn't know what to do

I guess the redirect url should be /sub/login, not simply /login.

There should be an easy way to configure the ingress to fix this trivial issue. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the whole ingress and service?

Comment: @Manuel Please see the posted manifests

Comment: Can you add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` under `metadata.annotations` in the Ingress manifest and check?

Comment: What else did you check already? Did cert-manager create the certificate correctly, checked the certificate resource? Is the domain pointing to the right ip address the ingress controller is bound to? Are you able to execute into the nginx controller and see what nginx.conf were generated out of the ingress? Is myapp running on port 80? Is the pod ready and healthy? The response of the url, is it already a response of the nginx ingress/default backend? Could be many reasons... The more information you can give us the better of course.

Comment: @Srijit_Bose-MSFT adding rewrite-target I get "404 Not found"

Comment: @Manuel Please note that with path: / everything works, which means that all the other components (cert manage etc) are ok. if it works with / it should simply work with /sub

Comment: Oh yes. Then of course forget what i said. :D i would guess it's a combination of pathType and the rewrite-target. On a 404 at least you should be able to see respons inside the logs. On ingress-controller or on the pod myapp. i can imagine, that the request path still will be forwarded to the pod, even if the pod is expecting the / path. pod will response with 404.

Comment: What about `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`? Just a blind shot.

Comment: @p10l same 404 with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`

Comment: what happens if you have multiple paths, ex: / and then /sub  ? and then try /sub, for the first one have a default backend.

Comment: @nen With both paths, / works while /sub gives 404