# Running multiple applications in the same AKS cluster with ingress controller(s) tls termination

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I managed to run successfully

- multiple applications in different namespaces with http
- one application with https (using cert-manager and letsencrypt)

But I need to run multiple https apps.

I tried two paths:

- Using [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323555/deploying-two-isolated-application-instances-with-nginx-ingress-and-tls-terminat?noredirect=1#comment122543625_69323555) dedicated ingress controllers+cert-managers
- Using [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312558/nginx-ingress-controller-routing-doesnt-work-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment122535440_69312558) controller+cert and route traffic with ingress rules

Is there an open source (complete) example of a working solution for this configuration? Also one based on Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) would do.

Comment: Have you considered one ingress controllers and then a separate cert per app? That's what I commonly see.

Comment: @ssc327 Yes I have considered that, but how to do it? Do I need 1 or 2 cert-managers? 1 or 2 cluster-issuers? 1 or 2 ingresses? What routing rules and annotations should I use?  I have tried multiple combinations, of which none works. That's why I am asking for an already running example.

Comment: You need only one ingress controller, cert-manager and cluster issuer. I am not aware of any examples but maybe I can make one for you. To get started, how is are your apps setup on k8s? Do you have multiple namespaces? Do you make ingress resources for each app?

Comment: In addition to comment above [here's a simple example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/multi-tls/) with two hosts using tls termination

Comment: @ssc327 Each app is (deployment+ClusterIP) service in a dedicated namespace. So  yes, multiple namespaces. About ingress I have an ingress per app, but if there is a better way I don't mind to change the design, just make it work.

Comment: @moonkotte I tried to use this example, however it doesn't fit directly to my use case so I had to try and adapt it. Unfortunately I didn't get it working.

Comment: Ok, I think I might see the issue. Usage of ClusterIP on service is not required if you have ingress setup. Would you be able to share what your service and ingress yaml look like?

Comment: @ssc327 Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312558/nginx-ingress-controller-routing-doesnt-work-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment122535440_69312558

Comment: @FrancoTiveron Link you shared contain `ingress` which doesn't even have `rewrite`. Please post here full ingress definition so it'll be possible to copy-paste and see what happens. Unfortunately there are not many complete examples, all use-cases are different. As an idea, you can use different `ingress rules` per `path` or `nginx inc plus` supports different `rewrites` per service - see [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites#syntax)

Comment: I ended up using a custom domain with wildcard DNS records. A little more expensive, but acceptable for my case